# Setting up Email Notifications based on time & location

Tags: applications, email, tasker

I'd ideally like to only receive notifications from an email app (can be the outlook app or the generic android mail app - not gmail or inbox) at certain times of the day or when I'm not connected to our office wifi. This is an exchange account, so using the gmail app isn't an option.

I know this is possible, most likely with Tasker, but I really can't figure it out, to be honest; and have done some searching here and elsewhere on how to do it. If someone could even lightly walk me through it, that would be excellent!

Comment: Is there a specific reason why not Gmail? Besides, which Android version and device are you using? Is the device rooted?

Answer (score 0):

There is an app called [IFTTT](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ifttt.ifttt&hl=en) (IfThisThenThat) which I have used before to schedule emails and SMS messages.